# How to pass an array of objects to the P5.js draw function?

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I have created an array of objects in the P5 setup() function and can draw them without issue.  However, when I try to draw the same object in the P5 draw() function it doesn't work.

I am guessing this is because I am not passing the object into the draw() method but I am having an issue because I don't understand how P5 draw() is called.

```
class Particle {
  constructor(x, y, size) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.size = size;
  }

  display() {
    ellipse(this.x, this.y, this.size, this.size); 
  }
}

function setup() {

  var screenWidth = 720;
  var screenHeight = 480;
  var numberOfParticles = 10;

  var particles = [];

  for (var idx = 0; idx < numberOfParticles; idx++) {
    size = Math.floor(Math.random() * 40) + 10;
    x = Math.floor(Math.random() * (screenWidth - (size * 2))) + size;
    y = Math.floor(Math.random() * (screenHeight - (size * 2))) + size;
    var p = new Particle(x, y, size);
    particles.push(p);
  }

  createCanvas(screenWidth,screenHeight);

  background(100,150,200);
  fill("yellow");

  // This displays the particles
  for (var idx = 0; idx < particles.length; idx++) {
    particles[idx].display();
  }

}

function draw() {
  fill("green");

  // This DOESN'T display the particles
  for (var idx = 0; idx < particles.length; idx++) {
    particles[idx].display();
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't pass arguments into the `draw()` function. The `draw()` function does not take any arguments.

Instead, just **define** the variable outside of both functions. Then you can **initialize** it in your `setup()` function, and use it inside the `draw()` function. Like this:

```
var textToDisplay;

function setup(){
   createCanvas(500, 500);
   textToDisplay = "hello world";
}

function draw(){
   background(64);
   text(textToDisplay, 100, 100);
}
```

Comment: That was it.  All I had to do was define the variables outside both the setup() and draw() functions and my sketch worked properly.  Thank you!!!